# Powershell Get-Childitem in ISE

Tags: powershell

please can you help me.
I'm missing some information.

Why when I execute the code:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName domainpc -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -path C:\Users -Filter "username1"}
```

the result is: **username1**

And when I execute this script:

```
    $user = Read-Host "Please enter username"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName domainpc -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -path C:\Users -Filter "$user"}
```

the result is a list of folder contained in C:\Users

I don't understand why executing script get different results than execute code without variable.
Seems that the problem is the variable.
Please can you explain this?

Thanks.

Comment: In the first code sample you have -Name and in the second one there is -Filter

Comment: sorry, I have corrected the code. Problem still persists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hitting scope "problems". 
The variable `$user` inside your script block `-ScriptBlock` is not known. 
Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.1#using-local-variables

Use `$Using:user` to get around.

Comment: sorry, I didn't write down here. My variable is $username and it's defined by the code: $username = read-host "Enter..."

Comment: @Diego Same solution, refer to `$using:username` inside the scriptblock

Comment: Could you explain, more detailed, what you are trying to do? And also update the whole code. Might it would be easier for us to help.

Comment: thanks to Patrick for the answer